# How to cancel an ongoing find/search in Sublime Text3

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

How can I cancel an ongoing search in sublime text?
basically when I do a recursive folder search for a particular text using

```
ctrl + shft + F
```

But sometimes it runs infinitely given a bad search pattern.
How to cancel a bad search of course without closing Sublime text?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the way to stop the search I use is to search again with an invalid path.
That does the trick for me. Hope that helps

Answer (score 4):

It is currently not possible to stop a "Find in Files" search once it has begun. Closing the "Find Results" panel or tab doesn't affect it - it only means you won't see any further results that are found.

It has been logged as an issue here:
https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1481

Comment: this issue has been fixed for ST4

Answer (score 2):

Looks like closing/re-opening Sublime stopped my search. Since Sublime starts up quickly with your previous tabs, this should be an easy operation.

Comment: @Trip, that's odd; is that because when you close Sublime it closes that find results file? Did you disable remember_open_files in your preferences?

Answer (score 0):

I believe if that panel is in "focus" you can simply hit the ESC key.

Comment: Just tried that. But that just closes the inputs/dialog. The search is still running